# how to replace multiple column in one column in txt file

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

I have a txt file file1.csv with 6 column. They are ordered like this:

```
$ cat file1.csv (tab delimited)(752 rows)
1   1011001 1001164 981328  1   -9
1   1011002 1001164 981328  1   -9
1   1011003 1001085 981149  1   -9
```

and

`$ cat file2.txt` (space delimited and it's a large file with 52872 column and 752 row)

```
1011001 CC GG TT AA ...
1011003 GG TT AA CC ...
1011002 TT GG CC AA ...
```

How can I replace of first column in file2.txt with all of 6 column in file1.csv as follow:

```
1   1011001 1001164 981328  1   -9  C   C   G   G   T   T   T   A   A   ...
1   1011002 1001164 981328  1   -9  T   T   G   G   C   C   A   A   
1   1011003 1001085 981149  1   -9  G   G   T   T   A   A   C   C
```

Comment: You mean like , 1   1011001 1001164 981328  1   -9 CC GG TT AA ... right? or one of your example in the question is not right?

Comment: I have two as : file1.cvs and file2.txt . i want to make 3th file. in file 3, the genotype  should be seperated and  6 columns in first file replace at first column on the second file.I mean yse just genotype sholud be seperated

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

file_1=pd.read_csv('file1.csv', header=None)
file_2=pd.read_csv('file2.txt', sep=' ')

combined_df = file_1.join(file_2, left_on=1, right_index=True)
```

Faisel makes a good point below.  You likely want to save the newly combined data to an output.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) package for easy manipulations of .csv file. In you case:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.txt')
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.txt')

df = pd.pd.concat([df1, df2], axix=1)

# Optionally save it back to csv file
df.to_csv('final.txt')
```